# .NET 7 Output caching in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, caching, outputcache, .net-7.0

I am using OutputCache in .NET7. Outputcache seems not working on IIS while it is working in my local or docker. Is there any configuration to set for IIS server?

```
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(options =>
{
    options.AddBasePolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.Expire(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    });
});
app.UseOutputCache();
```

```
        [HttpGet]
        [OutputCache]
        public async Task<IActionResult> getsomefunction()
        {
            return Ok(somefunction());
        }
```

Comment: Have you added `app.UseOutputCache();`?

Comment: yes it works on docker without any problem. when i publish it to IIS it does not cache the output.

Comment: _"it does not cache the output."_ - how do you verify that?

Comment: I am getting first response in 3 seconds while second and others in 50ms. In IIS every responses return in 3 seconds.

Comment: @Muratkscn that is not a very reliable approach to test caching.

Comment: how should I test caching then ? @GuruStron

Comment: I create an endpoint which returns `Guid.NewGuid()` and check if the result is changing. Also based n description output caching should be purely server-side so hosting should not affect it check if your app setup for some reason differ for IIS.

Comment: You could use [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing) to find the cause on IIS.